# Hibernate Class-to-Table Mapping Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlalchemy

I have worked with SQLAlchemy before, and from my experience I could do declarative mapping from classes to tables in SQLAlchemy before as well as the relationship between the classes.

Here is the example of the declaration:

```
class Item(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'item'

     id = Column(Integer, Sequence('item_seq'), primary_key=True)
     barcode = Column(String, unique=True)
     shortdesc = Column(String)
     desc   = Column(String)
     reg_date = Column(DateTime)
     registrar = Column(String)
     category = Column(String, ForeignKey('category.code'))
     supplier = Column(String, ForeignKey('supplier.code'))
     stock_on_hand = Column(Integer)
     cost = Column(Float)
     price = Column(Float)
     unit = Column(String, ForeignKey('unit.code'))

     receiving = relationship('Receiving', backref='item')
     adjustment = relationship('Adjustment', backref='item')
     sales = relationship('Sales', backref='sales')

     def __repr__(self):
        return "<Item('%s','%s','%s', '%s')>" % (self.barcode, self.shortdesc, self.stock_on_hand, self.unit)

class Supplier(Base):

     __tablename__ = 'supplier'

     code = Column(String, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String)
     reg_date = Column(DateTime)
     registrar = Column(String)
     address_line_1 = Column(String)
     address_line_2 = Column(String)
     address_line_3 = Column(String)
     postcode = Column(String)
     city = Column(String)
     state = Column(String)
     country = Column(String)
     phone = Column(String)
     fax = Column(String)
     representative = Column(String)

     item = relationship('Item',backref='supplier')

    def __repr__(self):
    return "<Supplier('%s','%s','%s')>" % (self.code, self.name, self.representative)
```

Where the `Supplier` has one-to-many relationship with `Item` and the table, as well as the relationship can be created from these classes declaration.

Can I do the same with Hibernate? How? I googled high and low, but I only found reverse engineering from table to class in Hibernate.

If it is possible to do like this, how do we handle relationship in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure that I understand your problem correctly, but here goes:

At it simplest, it can look like this:

```
public class Supplier {
    @Identity
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id; 
    //stuff
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="supplier")
    private List<Item> items;
    //more stuff
}

public class Item {
    @Identity
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id; 
    //item stuff
    @ManyToOne
    private Supplier supplier;
    //more item stuff
}
```

which states that a supplier has a number of items, and an item has a supplier. The mappedBy property states that in the database, the `Item`-table will have a column `supplier_id`, which a foreign key to the `Supplier`-table

Comment: Just to clarify thing up, we COULD use this class declaration to create tables in hibernate, am I right?

Comment: You could use a tool called hbm2ddl to generate the table definitions based on annotated classes (or hibernate mappings).

Comment: Dang, i thought it would be as simple as SQLAlchemy :(

Comment: It's not that much hazzle, if you use maven all you have to do is add a plugin to your pom.xml, and the database scheme can be generated through a simple command.